# How do I search through MATLAB command history?

Tags: search, matlab, history

I would like to search for a specific command I've previously used. Is it possible to do a free text search on MATLAB command history?

Comment: Closely related: [Recall command from history by command number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405536/history-command-buffer-in-matlab-call-by-command-number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to accomplish this in a programmatic and platform-independent manner, you can first use [MATLAB's Java internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585429/getting-help-on-matlabs-com-mathworks-internals) to get the command history as a character array:

```
history = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
historyText = char(history);
```

Then you can search through the character array however you like, using functions like [STRFIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html) or [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html). You can also turn the character array into a cell array of strings (one line per cell) with the function [CELLSTR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellstr.html), since they can sometimes be easier to work with.

Comment: @Jason S: It's not. Check out this other question: [Getting help on MATLAB's com.mathworks internals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585429)

Answer (score 25):

Yes.  Matlab stores your command history in a file called `history.m` in the "preferences folder," a directory containing preferences, history, and layout files.  You can find the preferences folder using the [`prefdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/prefdir.html) command:

```
>> prefdir

ans =

/home/tobin/.matlab/R2010a
```

Then search the `history.m` file in that directory using the mechanism of your choice.  For instance, using grep on unix:

```
>> chdir(prefdir)
>> !grep plot history.m
plot(f, abs(tf))
doc biplot
!grep plot history.m
```

You can also simply use the [search function in the command history window](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-17420.html#f0-23178) if you just want to use the GUI.

Comment: +1. Your answer is right. I accepted gnovice's answer because his solution also provides a regular expression option. Thanks anyway.

Comment: grep -E. (-:  Gnovice's answer is interesting too; I didn't know about the com.mathworks java interface.

Comment: If you click on the command history window, you can use `*` for simple regular expressions, e.g. `*plot` can match `h=plot(x,y)`.

Comment: The link to the page that you link to in the end seems to lead to a page that no longer exists. Do consider updating it. Perhaps it is [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/commandhistory.html) page?