# In Matlab, how can you move the document bar using a command?

Tags: ide, matlab

I have a bunch of docked figures in matlab.  Each one shows up as a tab in the document bar.  This is the bar that runs along the bottom of the figures window with a tab for each figure. This bar can be easily moved by clicking on the anchor and moving it to the left, right or top.  From the matlab help it says...

"Move the document bar.
Do one of the following:

Drag it to another location.
Select a new location from the Desktop > Document Bar > Bar Position submenu."

My question is, how can I do this with a command/script/code?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you take a look at Matlab editor API?

Comment: I'm not finding anything in the matlab help about an api for the editor.  If such a thing exists, I would imagine it would work, since the figure document bar seems to be the exact same as the editor document bar.

Comment: @MajorApus: `help matlab.desktop.editor`, but you wont find anything there to control the bar position. I suspect you'll have to go to [undocumented territory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2585429/97160) to achieve your goal... See if you can get @YairAltman's attention, the man is an expert in such things :)

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to move the dock bar but I have done some similar messing about with the command window when creating a gui. For example:

```
function SetCommandWindowDocked(docked)
   j_desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
   cmd_win = j_desktop.getClient('Command Window');
   j_desktop.setClientDocked(cmd_win,docked); 
end
```

I used Yair Altman's matlab utilities to sniff out the right objects/methods to use, see [matlab fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=authorid:27420).